# How to get all table names from db and paginate them

Tags: eloquent, laravel-query-builder, laravel-pagination

Trying to paginate `DB::select('SHOW TABLES')->paginate(1);` but got error `Call to a member function paginate() on array`. How can I get all the tables and paginate them?

Comment: make it a collection and then paginate

Comment: I am new to laravel, I know few things but not sure how to mix them and use

Comment: can u please show me

Comment: check the official documentation for collections
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections

Answer (score 0):

Since you can use `\DB:select` for your query, it will response the array instead of the collection. So, you can't make the pagination from it.

You can use LengthAwarePaginator for this case, please see the following code:

```
$sql .= 'SHOW TABLES LIMIT ' . $offset . ', ' . $limit; 

$result = \DB::select(\DB::raw($sql));
$myPaginator = new \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator($result, $data['count'], $limit, $page, ['path' => action('MyController@index')]);
$data['result'] = $result;
```